# What’s the deal with the tongue?

Tags: plot-explanation, true-detective

Annie, is killed years earlier and her tongue is cut out. Then, in the present day (in '*True Detective: Night Country*) the tongue re-appears in Tsalal Station. It was found after everyone had disappeared.

**Who cut it out and why did they decide to place it in Tsalal?**

Comment: @Valorum the tag is for the whole TV show, not per-season, why did you remove the season? It's important info.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda - Does it happen more than once in the show?

Comment: @Valorum no, but I think it's helpful to specify the season.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda - I agree, but you might want to put that in the body of the question

Comment: @Valorum well yes, but you just removed it so assumed it might be considered noise or something like that. Thanks for the new edit, that's good enough. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's left deliberately vague, so we don't know.

This was a deliberate choice by the creators.

> Night Country creator Issa López said the tongue’s reappearance was left purposefully ambiguous. “That’s one that I’m not going to be telling you because my goal was to give you the possibility of choosing your answers here,” López told Business Insider. “There are many ways that tongue could have ended up there. Some of them are natural and some of them are not.”
>
> [Source](https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/news/true-detective-season-4-episode-6-annie-k-tongue-b2499845.html)